# terminal shell behaves differently from normal shell

Tags: terminal, shell

I run this command in a common terminal:

```
$ ps aux | grep work | grep python | awk '{print $2}'
```

Then I have three different pids, however, in the vim-term window, the same line gave me two pids. From observation, it seems that it has ignored the first one, what is the cause of this ?

Comment: Drop the awk at the end and then provide the output from the common terminal and the vim-term.

Comment: The vim-term isn't showing the pid for the grep command itself like the common terminal is.

Comment: @Ralf Still missing, this time it has left two pids.

Comment: Most likely the grep(s) are missing (like Eric said), but the real question is: Why? Could you provide Vim version, OS and shell?